# Saving contents to file with formatting details in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, formatting, filewriter

I am working on a VB.NET project that retrieves data from the specified database and saves the result into a file with a unique extension (viz. *.vcs). The thing that troubles me is that I need to save the data with user defined formatting (e.g. font color, font size, etc) so that he finds it in the same format when he accesses the file again in future. Any suggestion as to how can this be done?

Comment: So, in which format is the data when you retrieve it form the database?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access 2007 (.accdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdc88y7.aspx) control to save (`RichTextBox.SaveFile()`) and load (`RichTextBox.LoadFile()`) content in RTF format.

Comment: Thanx AVD, does this work with tables like the one I'm dealing with?